# How to send the checkbox value to email

Tags: ajax, wp-mail

**HTML** of form is given below

```
<?php                             
 for($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i)
 {                  
     if($emails[$i]!=""){                        
     $userId=$emails[$i]['ID'];
     $user_info = get_users($userId); 
     echo"<tr class='iedit alternate'>
     <td  class='name column-name' style='border:1px solid #DBDBDB;padding-left:13px;'><input type='checkbox' id='haet_mail_test_address' name='ckboxs[]'  value='".$emails[$i]['user_email']."'>&nbsp;".$emails[$i]['user_email']."</td>";
      echo "<td  class='name column-name' style='border:1px solid #DBDBDB;'> ".$user_info->user_login."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
     }                              
}                       
?>
<button class="button-primary" id="haet_mail_test_submit" name="submit" type="submit">Send Email</button>
<div id="haet_mail_test_sent" class="haet-mail-dialog" title="<?php _e('Email sent','wp-html-mail'); ?>">
<p>
<?php _e('Your message has been sent.','wp-html-mail'); ?>
</p>
```

below my **Javascript** code

```
$('#haet_mail_test_submit').click(function(){
    var checkbox = $('#haet_mail_test_address').val();
    $.post(ajaxurl, { 'action':'haet_mail_send_test', 'checkbox':checkbox} , function(response) {
        $( "#haet_mail_test_sent" ).dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "OK",
                    click: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

**AJAX** function is given below

```
function send_test() {
    $email= $_POST['checkbox'];
    echo $email;        
    wp_mail( $email, ''.$email.'');
    wp_die();
}
```

I am new on Wordpress so how I can send the checkbox values to wp_mail

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a class for all checkbox as having same id for multiple items is not recommended

```
<input type='checkbox' class="new_class" id='haet_mail_test_address' name='ckboxs[]'  value='".$emails[$i]['user_email']."'>
```

Now we to change the way you are getting the values from checkbox

Change

`var checkbox = $('#haet_mail_test_address').val();`

To

```
var checkbox = $(".new_class:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(checkbox); // check if you are getting the values here
```

Now in "checkbox" you will get an array of selected checkbox values. Now you can pass it to the ajax function as data

Comment: in my email subject the value are array is showing how to remove this

Comment: What are you really trying to implement? How you want your email to be like??

Comment: I want to send bulk email through my custom plugin